# SoapClient Multiple ComplexTypes Same Name

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

So I've got a client who has a SOAP Based Service with a WSDL. I've been mostly successful in interacting with it, however there are three complexTypes with the name "LineItem."

The last of these doesn't have the field "ExtraData" and for some reason SoapClient is defaulting to that version of the complexType. Is there a way for me to specify which of these I would like to use?

Comment: For now I'm just using a local WSDL but if there is a way to choose which complexType I want to use that would be awesome.